# Dataframe summary math based on condition from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have what amounts to 3D data but can't install the Pandas recommended [xarray package](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/).

#### df_values

```
   | a    b    c
-----------------
0  | 5    9    2
1  | 6    9    5
2  | 1    6    8
```

#### df_condition

```
   | a    b    c
-----------------
0  | y    y    y
1  | y    n    y
2  | n    n    y
```

I know I can get the average of all values in `df_values` like this.

```
df_values.stack().mean()
```

Question...  
What is the simplest way to find the `average of df_values` where `df_condition == "y"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wish to find the mean of all values where `df_condition == 'y'`:

```
res = np.nanmean(df_values[df_condition.eq('y')])  #5.833333333333333
```

Using NumPy is substantially cheaper than Pandas `stack` or `where`:

```
# Pandas 0.23.0, NumPy 1.14.3
n = 10**5
df_values = pd.concat([df_values]*n, ignore_index=True)
df_condition = pd.concat([df_condition]*n, ignore_index=True)

%timeit np.nanmean(df_values.values[df_condition.eq('y')])       # 32 ms
%timeit np.nanmean(df_values.where(df_condition == 'y').values)  # 88 ms
%timeit df_values[df_condition.eq('y')].stack().mean()           # 107 ms
```

Comment: Interesting jpp. My actual dataframes are pretty big so this option may prove very useful. `df.where` is meant to be `df_values.where`, yeah?

Comment: @GollyJer, Not using `where` here, but should be `df_values`. I've also corrected a minor error, see update.

Comment: Testing all these approaches... `np.nanmean(df_values.values[df_condition.eq('y')])` returns the wrong answer.

Comment: @GollyJer, I see it returning `5.833333333333333`. What do you see it returning?

Comment: Strange... I get `6.22222222222`. The others all return `5.833333333333333`.

Comment: @GollyJer, OK. Unfortunately, I can't replicate.

Comment: I think it's the version of Python I'm stuck with... that one also throws this error. `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:9: FutureWarning: in the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a boolean array index`  Thanks again for the help! 

Comment: @GollyJer, Possibly. I'm using 3.7. Note soon 2.7 will no longer be officially supported.

Comment: Yeah if I can help it I only use 3.7. Hopefully https://www.quantopian.com upgrades their platform some day. 

Answer (score 1):

IIUC Boolean mask

```
df[c.eq('y')].mean().mean()
6.5
```

Or you may want

```
df[c.eq('y')].sum().sum()/c.eq('y').sum().sum()
5.833333333333333
```

Comment: Thanks W-B. I had to look up what IIUC means... If I Understand Correctly... right? 

Comment: @GollyJer yep . :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the mean of all values where the condition is 'y' with only pandas DataFrame and Series methods like below

```
df_values[df_condition.eq('y')].stack().mean()  # 5.833333333333333
```

or

```
df_values[df_condition == 'y'].stack().mean()  # 5.833333333333333
```

Is this simple? :)

Comment: Very simple.  Thanks duckdeok.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
np.nanmean(df.where(dfcon == 'y').values)
```

Output:

```
5.8333333333
```